# InvalidManifest. HTTP 403 (Forbidden) when registering image to EC2

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, http-status-code-403

I'm encountring some problems when I try to register an AMI to ec2. This is what I've do: I've downloaded an AMI already existing into my s3 bucket, this ami can be registered without any problems. (When i try on the web app, with this existing ami)

I re-upload it on a new bucket, when a try to register the AMI from the newly created bucket it fails with this error:

Status Code: 400, AWS Service: AmazonEC2, AWS Request ID: X, AWS Error Code: InvalidManifest, AWS Error Message: HTTP 403 (Forbidden) response for URL http://s3.amazonaws.com:80/testclementusnew/0/node_ec2_infra.manifest.xml: check your S3 ACLs are correct.

I use the same account to upload and register and in the Permissions section of the files my account has all the permission.

I'm using the latest version of the java SDK, I specify the following endpoints for s3 and ec2:
ec2endPoint=ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
s3endPoint=s3.amazonaws.com

I've also tried on european endpoints and same error ...

The bucket is also located on the good s3 endpoint.

Does everyone has an idea how to solve this error ?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty hacky workaround, but this worked for me:

First you need to `wget http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem` to get an updated CA cert list.

Then, edit the ec2-ami-tools curl lib. Mine was in:

```
/usr/lib/ec2-ami-tools/lib/ec2/common/curl.rb
```

I changed line 68 from

```
invocation << ' -w "Response-Code: %{http_code}\nContent-Type: %{content_type}"'
```

to

```
invocation << ' -w "Response-Code: %{http_code}\nContent-Type: %{content_type}" --cacert /path/to/cacert.pem'
```